# Not able to format SD card

Tags: format, sd-card

I have the following disks:

```
tatiana@berlin ~ $ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0rpmb  179:24   0    4M  0 disk 
mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0      179:0    0 29,1G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p4  179:4    0  6,6G  0 part /home
├─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0 18,6G  0 part /
├─mmcblk0p3  179:3    0  191M  0 part /boot/efi
└─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  3,7G  0 part [SWAP]
```

My first question is: why are there 3 disks mmcblk0rpmb, mmcblk0boot0 and mmcblk0boot1, when I have only one SD card? mmcblk0 is the disk where I have my linux distribution installed.

Also I have the following:

```
tatiana@berlin ~ $ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29,1 GiB, 31268536320 bytes, 61071360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9B2ADCED-F492-4EDF-AC8D-D29AD20B8E35

Device            Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1     2048  7813119  7811072  3,7G Linux swap
/dev/mmcblk0p2  7813120 46874623 39061504 18,6G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk0p3 46874624 47265791   391168  191M EFI System
/dev/mmcblk0p4 47265792 61069311 13803520  6,6G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Why fdisk doesn't list mmcblk0rpmb as lsblk does?

Finally, when I open gparted, it only shows mmcblk0. To open other disks I have to write, e.g. `gparted /dev/mmcblk0boot1`. There I create a partition table, but fail to do so and get the message `Operation not permitted during write on /dev/mmcblk0boot0` The same happens with mmcblk0boot1.

How do I format the SD card? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please tell us more about your SD card. There seems to be an operating system on it.  What operating system? How did you create it? What does it look like, when connected some other way, for example in another computer or via a USB adapter?

Comment: I've run into the same issue, my SD card has Ubuntu core on it for a Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. After trying both Gparted and manually removing the partitions from `fdisk` I ended up using Windows' *Computer management* tool. From there, right click the corresponding volume(s) and delete them.

Once you've done that, you can format it correctly from Ubuntu using Gparted or whichever tool you want. I'm not sure why Linux wasn't able to handle it, but it seems to be a low level conflict, and the dreaded "Operation not permitted during write" error doesn't give any pointer about what is failing precisely.

I know "using Windows" is not the best answer, but in this case it happened to be the only alternative that worked.

Comment: I see no sign that the OP has a Windows installation here. One should use Windows tools to manage Windows partitions, and trying to modify them from a Linux system often fails. I think the OP's problem must be very different to yours.